# Is a countable, nowhere compact, zero-dimensional, dense in itself, Hausdorff space which is 2nd countable; homeomorphic to space of rationals?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a countable, nowhere compact, zero-dimensional, dense in itself, Hausdorff space which is 2nd countable. Is $X$ homeomorphic to the space of rationals?

$X$ is called nowhere compact when for every compact subset $A \subseteq X$ we have $\operatorname{Int} A = \emptyset$.

Comment: Not answering to your question, but you should have stated your thoughts.

Comment: I's a part of a proof in a paper. The author uses Sierpinski's theorem to conclude this, but I don't understand how!!

Comment: Sierpinski's theorem states that: All countable dense in itself sets (located in a Euclidean space to any number of dimensions) are homeomorphic.

Comment: I think using the Urysohn's metrization theorem we can conclude that $X$ is metrizable. And then Sierpinski's theorem implies that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Mostafa: Yes, that’s correct. And you don’t actually need the hypothesis that $X$ is nowhere compact.